# Where to download the dynamic version of the firebase frameworks

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I do not use xcode but Delphi development tool, and I would like to know where I can download the dynamic version of the firebase frameworks. as far as I understand the version under https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/releases are only the static framework right ?

Comment: zeus, I have updated the links in the comment for your reference, do let me know if they were helpful.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar thanks but it's not this. i learn that their is no dynamic binary of the firebase

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with CocoaPods 1.9.0 and Firebase 7, you can choose whether your Firebase [dependencies are built as static or dynamic frameworks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/link-firebase-static-dynamic). recommendation is using static frameworks unless you require certain [dynamic library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/link-firebase-static-dynamic#dynamic_linking) behaviors.
Using Firebase SDKs from dynamic framework conclusion:

- Firebase may be used from an embedded dynamic framework in your project (e.g. for the code reuse purposes) only when Firebase is not used from the app directly.
- Firebase SDKs should never be used from vendor dynamic frameworks because the version of Firebase compiled into the dynamic framework will early or later conflict with the customer Firebase version.

Check the helpful official documentation for [Android related dynamic feature modules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#dynamic-feature-modules)  and [Android play services required](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/android-play-services#google-play-services-required-recommended) recommendations.

Comment: thanks, but where to download the library?

Comment: IOS-[Mach-O Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachOTopics/0-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001827-SW1)
[Dynamic Library Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html)
[Using Firebase in libraries](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/firebase_in_libraries.md)

Comment: For Android check below-
[Firebase dynamic library](com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:21.1.0)
[Firebase dynamic library2](com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx:21.1.0)

Comment: no you don't understand, I need to know where to download the dynamic version of the library on iOS

Comment: Check the links below:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/firebase_in_libraries.md
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/FirebaseDynamicLinks
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/tree/master/FirebaseDynamicLinks/Sources